# Read files on UNC path using File Connector - WSO2 EI(Linux)

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, unc, file-connection

How to Read files on UNC path using File Connector on WSO2 EI(Linux)? I am getting the below error while trying to read the file in a UNC location

```
WARN {API_LOGGER.FileMigration} - Executing fault handler due to exception encountered
WARN {API_LOGGER.FileMigration} - ERROR_CODE : 90001 ERROR_MESSAGE : FILE_CONNECTOR:FILE_OR_DIR_NOT_EXIST
WARN {API_LOGGER.FileMigration} - Executing fault sequence mediator : 
INFO {API_LOGGER.FileMigration} - text = An unexpected error occured, message = FILE_CONNECTOR:FILE_OR_DIR_NOT_EXIST
```

Do we have to have any specific connectivity established to read/copy/write a file to and from `UNC`(Windows) to `WSO2` EI(Linux)?

Note: File is in the defined location.

Tried using @"sourceLocation", \\sourceLocation in the source path. Non of them worked.

Comment: sudo mount.cifs \\\\{source} {destination} -o {username} worked.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/reference/connectors/file-connector/3.x/file-connector-3.x-config/), the UNC paths are supported. The following is from the official documentation.

> For local files, the URI format is [file://]absolute-path, where
> absolute-path is a valid absolute file name for the local platform.
> UNC names are supported under Windows (e.g., file:///home/user/test or
> file:///C:/Windows).

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but it says - " UNC names are supported under Windows " 
One, I am using a Linux box and when I try reading it using File Connector, it still says file not found

Comment: It seems it's only supported in Windows environments. How about mounting the location to the Linux box and accessing through a Unix path?